# Building Typescript: [!] Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, rollupjs, lerna, monorepo

I've encountered problem building typescript packages with rollup inside lerna managed monorepo.

[Error](https://gist.github.com/moki/89e935193b7d5911b7b0452e0de3e0a6):

```
lerna ERR! rollup --config ../../rollup.config.js stderr:
loaded ../../rollup.config.js with warnings
(!) Unused external imports
terser imported from external module 'rollup-plugin-terser' but never used

index.ts → dist/esm...
[!] Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
../mokui-base/component.ts (3:7)
1: const root = Symbol("root");
2: 
3: export type Component<T extends object = {}> = T & {
          ^
4:         [root]: Element;
5:         attach(element: Element): Component<T>;
Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
    at error (/****/****/code/js/mokui/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:5351:30)
    at Module.error (/****/****/code/js/mokui/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:9643:9)
    at tryParse (/****/****/code/js/mokui/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:9552:16)
    at Module.setSource (/****/****/code/js/mokui/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:9868:33)
    at Promise.resolve.catch.then.then.then (/****/****/code/js/mokui/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:12148:20)


lerna ERR! rollup --config ../../rollup.config.js exited 1 in '@moki.codes/mokui-header'
```

Error points at "export type" tokens which is well... confusing, how come typescript doesn't understand own constructs i am not sure.

One will be able to reproduce error by cloning [repository](https://github.com/moki/mokui) and running `yarn build:packages`
@master branch.

Interestingly enough `mokui-base` package which defines `Component` builds just fine by itself, giving the error above on build only when one depend on it like i do inside the `mokui-header`. Reproducible by adding

```
if (process.env.LERNA_PACKAGE_NAME === "@moki.codes/mokui-header")
    process.exit(0);
```

at the top of the `rollup.config.js` and running `yarn build:packages`.

I also have another build target "dev" one can try with `yarn build:dev` which builds from `stories/index.ts`, and serves at `localhost:3000`. It is relevant to the question because there, `mokui-header` `Header` builds just fine depending on the `mokui-base` `Component`, `Header` factory is used inside `index.ts` and gives no errors, works as intented and provides defined behavior.

My first instinct was to opt out of the cjs build because thats the main difference between two builds(build:packages and build:dev), but that didn't make any difference, so that leaves with the `@organization/package` resolution problem i guess, i am not sure... not like i know where to go from there if that's the case. Removing `export` at `export type Component =...` inside `component.ts` source gets rid of the error, but of course that spawns the new error inside the `mokui-header` `HeaderComponent` complaining that `Component is a value but used as type`, because well... there is no `Component` type export to consume anymore.

So yeah, if you have any ideas where should i go from here or know exactly how i should go about building typescript package, which depends on the other sibling one please do share them.

I am sorry if i come off as rude but please don't recommend me opting out of the custom build and use preconfigured boilerplate or something of that sort.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In case anyone encounters the same problem, below i am providing solution:

When one attempts to build each separate package inside the monorepo, rollup attempts to resolve `@organization/package-name` and include it in the build. You don't want that, so to avoid it upon building each package i am parsing `package.json`, extracting the `dependencies` field's keys, then to check against them inside the `callback` one can provide inside rollup config's `external` field. This will produce the desired outcome.

```
import json from "rollup-plugin-json";

const pkg = process.env.LERNA_PACKAGE_NAME &&
          require(`${process.env.LERNA_PACKAGE_NAME}/package.json`);

const dependencies = ({ dependencies }) => Object.keys(dependencies || {});

const pkgdependencies = dependencies(pkg);

/* exported rollup configuration */
const config = {
    /* your config goes here... */
    /* id is the source name if list of dependencies includes
     * id source name, then mark it as external,
     */
    external: id => pkgdependencies.includes(id)
};

export default config;
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error message, also using `lerna`.

For me **updating `typescript` to version `4.2.3`** did the trick.

I found the solution in [an issue on the `rollup/plugins` repo](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/issues/287).

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this answer. I just wasted several hours trying to figure out what was going wrong. Don't know what I would have done if I hadn't ran across this.

Answer (score 1):

I also have this problem，my solution is use [`@rollup/plugin-sucrase`](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/sucrase) or `acorn-jsx`

```
  import sucrase from '@rollup/plugin-sucrase';

  export default [
    ...

    sucrase({
        exclude: ['node_modules/**'],
        transforms: ['typescript', 'jsx'],
      }),
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this building error(vue build error :
rolluperror: unexpected token (note that you need plugins to import files that are not javascript) )

for three days, when I checked vite.config.ts:

```
 export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue({ 
      template: { transformAssetUrls }
    }),
    // https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/tree/next/packages/vite-plugin
    vuetify({
      autoImport: true,
      styles: {
        configFile: 'src/styles/settings.scss',
      },
    }),
  ],
  define: { 'process.env': {}, 'global':{} },
// rest of code
```

I took 'global':{} out of define and then yarn build ran with no more errors.
In summary, removing global: {} from your Vite configuration likely resolved the build error because it allowed the necessary global variables to be available for your application and its dependencies to function properly during the build process. If the default global variables are needed by the code or dependencies you're using, removing this configuration is the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

I had the error because I relied on Webstorm auto-import ‍♂️.

I hav a main project that imports two libraries A and B from a npm mono-repo. A is using B.

I developed a change in B that I auto-imported in A.

Instead of resolving it as:

```
import {myNewFunction} from '@org/B';
```

Webstorm imported it as:

```
import {myNewFunction} from '@org/B/src';
```

What was fine for both build and test of the library but, when I finally used the libs locally in my main project, I faced OP's error too.

Correcting manually the import - removing the `/src` - fixed the issue.

Answer (score -2):

Clearing (manually deleting) the `*.d.ts` files, created by the previous rollup will solve the issue. If you have `dist` folder (folder in which rollup files will be created), clear it.
This resolved issue for me.